# How to get group children view in expandable listview and countdown timer?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, countdowntimer

I came across this problem, i have a expandablelistview and a countdown timer. With countdown timer i want to expand a group and update textview with time remaining. I didn't find any solution online, that's why i am writting here.

How can i access View from Timer?

this is my expandable listview code:

```
public class ExerciseListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private View childview, rowview;
    private List<List<Bitmap>> vajeImage;
    private ArrayList<ExerciseItem> headers;

    public ExerciseListAdapter(View ChView, View RView, List<List<Bitmap>> vaje, ArrayList<ExerciseItem> header) {
        this.childview = ChView;
        this.rowview = RView;
        this.vajeImage = vaje;
        this.headers = header;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return headers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return vajeImage.get(i).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return headers.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return vajeImage.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_elv_row, viewGroup, false);
        TextView txHead = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewExeHead);
        txHead.setText(headers.get(i).getIme());
        TextView txSub = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewExeSub);
        txSub.setText(headers.get(i).getOpis());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_elv_child_item, viewGroup, false);
        ImageView imview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageviewChild);
        imview.setImageBitmap(vajeImage.get(i).get(i1));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

And this is my timer code

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    int current=0;
    ExpandableListView EL;
    TextView timeText;
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval, ExpandableListView list) {
        super(startTime, interval);
        EL=list;
        list.expandGroup(current);

        //this returns null pointer exception on TextView tx           
        list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if(EL.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    TextView tx = (TextView) EL.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
                    tx.setText("2");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //timeText.setText("Time's up!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //timeText.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        Log.v("test","" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here i try to access public methods of my adapter, adapter class is public, methods are public, but not found

```
                if(EL.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    //epl.setChildViewData(groupPosition, 0, "2");

                   epl=(ExpandableListAdapter)EL.getExpandableListAdapter();
                    //cannot resolve method "notifyDataSetChanged
                   epl.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want ? At the end of timer all child should expand ?? or when ?

Comment: Selected group should expand when i create new timer, it does so. I want to update child view of that expanded group, but i cant access it.

Comment: what did you do to access it ? and what exception did you face ?

Comment: TextView tx returns null exception when i try to set string "2" to it. I'm not even sure how should i access expanded group child, thats why firstly i expanded selected group and then i tried to access it through ongroupexpand listener it does not work tho.

Comment: Did you try to create the class inside the adapter? As a class in class. In that way it would be much easier to access the variables from the adapter.

Comment: At the moment, i have fragment and adapter class inside it.

Comment: A rookie mistake, i had to set my adapter to private class and not public!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `childview` that your trying to access is not created when you make the call. So in your `setOnGroupExpandListener()` the child views are not yet created so your getting that exception, so you have to wait until all the views are created to make the modifications

I would suggest you to pass the values to the adapter so that it makes the modifications. Something like this

In your `ExerciseListAdapter` file add this `HashMap`

```
private HashMap<String, String> mMapStuff =new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Also add a this method in adapter

```
public void setChildViewData(int groupPosition, int childPosition, String value){
    mMapStuff.put(groupPosition+""+childPosition, value);
}
```

and now in your `getChildView()` method

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Some Other Code 
    .....

    //Note this should be your last line before the return statement
    String msg = mMapStuff.get(groupPosition+""+childPosition);
    if(msg != null)
        txtListChild.setText(msg);
    return convertView;
}
```

And now in your `setOnGroupExpandListener()` add this line

```
listAdapter.setChildViewData(groupPosition, 0, "2");
```

like this

```
//this returns null pointer exception on TextView tx           
list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        listAdapter.setChildViewData(groupPosition, 0, "2");
    }
});
```

let me know if this works

Comment: for some strange reason i cant access setChildViewData method, altough its public...

Comment: What error are your getting ? your adapter class public right ? Where are you trying to access it pls paste the code

Comment: See my edited first post. Adapter class is public, methods are public, really weird behavior.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! thank you, i wasn't familiar with updating of expandablelistview before.

Comment: Hello @GirishNair I want a requirement for like this I have an Audio player in child part of an expandable list . In audio playing, there is play/pause button for playing. If i want to open other expandable list  then previous child is closed and Audio player should be stop. Its works fine but the issue is **play/pause button is not getting change from pause to play**